# Generate due dates using function in a select statement SQL SERVER

Tags: sql-server

I want to create a semi - monthly amortization schedule by using a function.

Here is my function:

```
CASE WHEN day(@dt) < 16 
THEN 
   CASE WHEN month(@dt) = 2 -- IF FEBRUARY, THEN GET LAST DAY OF MONTH 
   THEN 
      eomonth(@dt) 
   ELSE -- SET AS 30 
      dateadd(day, 30-day(@dt), @dt) end 
ELSE 
   dateadd(month, 1, dateadd(day, 15-day(@dt), @dt)) -- SET AS 15  
END
```

Let's say I already have a table of schedule like this

```
instno |  amount   |  duedate    
------------------------------
1      |  1000.00  |  1-30-2020
2      |  1000.00  |  NULL
3      |  1000.00  |  NULL
4      |  1000.00  |  NULL
5      |  1000.00  |  NULL
```

I want to fill the remaining 4 installments using the function I created or similar.

So far, I have tried doing,

```
select *,
    dbo.duedategenerator(LAG(duedate,1,'1-30-2020') OVER (ORDER BY b.ilno)) 
from table
```

Output should be like this:

```
instno |  amount   |  duedate    
------------------------------
1      |  1000.00  |  1-30-2020
2      |  1000.00  |  2-15-2020
3      |  1000.00  |  2-29-2020
4      |  1000.00  |  3-15-2020
5      |  1000.00  |  3-30-2020
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if the following answers your question relating to the function, but I thought to put this answer out there, for reasons that it might change the way you're thinking about this and might assist you in resolving your query through this.

I thought about what you're looking for and according to me this can be resolved with a `cursor`, which is not essential but gives you the exact results you require:

```
declare @tblresult  table (instno int primary key identity, amount float, duedate date)

declare @amount     float
,       @startdate  date
,       @duedate    date

declare @tbl        table (instno int primary key identity, amount float, duedate date)

insert into @tbl (amount,duedate) values (1000,'1-30-2020')
insert into @tbl (amount,duedate) values (1000,null)
insert into @tbl (amount,duedate) values (1000,null)
insert into @tbl (amount,duedate) values (1000,null)
insert into @tbl (amount,duedate) values (1000,null)
insert into @tbl (amount,duedate) values (1000,'7-30-2020')
insert into @tbl (amount,duedate) values (1000,null)
insert into @tbl (amount,duedate) values (1000,null)
insert into @tbl (amount,duedate) values (1000,null)
insert into @tbl (amount,duedate) values (1000,null)

declare selectcursor cursor for 

select
    amount
,   duedate
from    @tbl

open selectcursor

fetch next from selectcursor into @amount, @duedate

while @@fetch_status = 0

begin

    if @duedate is not null

        begin

            set @startdate = @duedate

            insert into @tblresult (amount,duedate) values (@amount,@startdate)

        end

    else

        begin

            set @duedate    = dateadd(d,15,@startdate)

            insert into @tblresult (amount,duedate) values (@amount,@duedate)

            set @startdate  =   dateadd(d,15,@startdate)

        end

    fetch next from selectcursor into @amount, @duedate

end

close selectcursor

deallocate selectcursor


select
*
from    @tblresult
```

You will notice that I added extra records to show that it's working...

The above results looks like this:

[image: Expected Results]

You can also see these results of [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=18c2b14b3be2c53cfec7af3156b962fa)

Comment: Hi, actually I already have a solution created with cursor. I was thinking maybe there is something better I could use. Since I have 100k+ records to update and it takes 10 - 12 mins to process. Thanks.